# Wrong UI on real device (IOS) flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter

I have problems with the UI on real device (IOS) but in the emulator (same iphone) the UI is right. The app is developed with Flutter. The problem is only in iOS

Iphone SE 1st Generation (Emulator device):

[image: emulator device]

Iphone SE 1st Generation (Real device):

[image: real device]

Any idea of this behavior?

Edit:

I tried with real device(connected by usb) and is working correctly. The problem is when I use the app in TestFlight.

Any idea? I don't know what to do

Comment: Hola! This grey box looks like that there is a error going on... Is this a ListView or something like that?

Comment: There is an error. So, you need to debug it with real device.

Comment: most likely the data used in that `Widget` can not be fetched while using a real device

Comment: I'm downloading XCode 14.1 to test on iOS 15.7. I'll tell you guys any update